# What happens during a Jupyter notebook evaluation?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've always thought that Jupyter simply printed out the `repr` of an object, but that is not the case.

Here is an example. If I evaluate this in a notebook:

```
obj = type(2)
obj
```

I just get: `int`.

If I do instead

```
print(obj)
```

I get: `<class 'int'>`.

So: what is the Python instruction to simulate what the notebook does during the evaluation of a variable?

Comment: You know Jupyter is open-source, right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with evaluating the variable, it's merely about *representing* the variable. If your question is about how to *replicate* the representation, you should either look up how Jupyter implements it, or specify what kind of representation your require - e.g. having types represented by their class name.

Comment: Maybe this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter/IPython uses a rather complex [pretty printer](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/pretty.py). Concerning your example of `int`, it has a [printer for classes/type](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/pretty.py#L668).

Basically what it does is it gets the class' name via `cls.__qualname__` (py3) or `cls.__name__` (py2&3) and the module via `cls.__module__`, and prints them as `<module.name>`. For builtins, the module name is silently ignored.